What is the name of this bypass valve quick connect adapter?
While reworking the supply going to my water softener, I damaged the threads on the 1" threaded PVC male to softener bypass, and now I need to replace the part.
I am having trouble finding the part because I do not know the correct terminology.
What is the proper name of this type of connection? In the image below, both the red and green arrows point to them; they are both some form of plastic, and push into the bypass valve; they are held in place with the pictured black clips.
The red side has female threads that connector to the softener control head; the green side has male threads that connect to the water supply.
(The threads I damaged are actually on the green side connection, but I don't have a picture of that.)



Have you contacted the manufacturer? What about the dealer / supplier?
